# Can't achieve jumping in Javascript Game

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing a Javascript game (almost everything is based on a tutorial yet, so I am not worried of sharing the code).

The problem is, I can't get the character to jump after pressing the Space button. Please, can someone look at the code and help me?

// EDIT: Sorry for lack of information I provided. The thing is - code is written, the game is in the state, that the character is animated (=is running) and the backgrounds are moving. Yesterday, I tried to implement some basic controls, such as jump by pressing spacebar. The thing is, the player won't jump at all, and browser console is not giving me any error statements.

Character is defined as Player on line 5. and 321. in the code provided below.

The jumping is defined in the following examples:

**Pressing the Space button**

```
    var KEY_CODES = {
    32: 'space'
  };
  var KEY_STATUS = {};
  for (var code in KEY_CODES) {
    if (KEY_CODES.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
       KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
    }
  }
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
      e.preventDefault();
      KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
    }
  };
  document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
      e.preventDefault();
      KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
    }
  };
```

**Other jump information** (please, read the comments in the code)

```
this.update = function() {

      // jump, if the characted is NOT currently jumping or falling
      if (KEY_STATUS.space && this.dy === 0 && !this.isJumping) {
        this.isJumping = true;
        this.dy = this.jumpDy;
        jumpCounter = 12;
        assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
      }

      // longer jump if the space bar is pressed down longer
      if (KEY_STATUS.space && jumpCounter) {
        this.dy = this.jumpDy;
      }

      jumpCounter = Math.max(jumpCounter-1, 0);

      this.advance();

      // gravity
      if (this.isFalling || this.isJumping) {
        this.dy += this.gravity;
      }

      // change animation is-falling
      if (this.dy > 0) {
        this.anim = this.fallAnim;
      }
      // change animation is-jumping
      else if (this.dy < 0) {
        this.anim = this.jumpAnim;
      }
      else {
        this.anim = this.walkAnim;
      }

      this.anim.update();
    };

       /**
     * Update the Sprite's position by the player's speed
     */
    this.update = function() {
      this.dx = -player.speed;
      this.advance();
    };
    /**
     * Draw the current player's frame
     */
    this.draw = function() {
      this.anim.draw(this.x, this.y);
    };
  }
  Player.prototype = Object.create(Vector.prototype);
```

Everything seems just fine to me, but the player just won't move. :(

Any help?

If you are curious about the full code, go here: http://pastebin.com/DHZKhBMT

**EDIT2:**

Thank you very much for your replies so far.

I have moved the `RequestAnimFrame` to the end of the function - will keep that in mind, thanks.

I have also implemented the simple jumping script Ashish provided above, but the character is still not jumping.

This is what it looks like now:

```
/** JUMP KEYS DEFINITION **/

    $(document).keypress(function(e){

        if(e.which==32){

            $('Player.prototype').css({'top':"0px"});

        }

    setTimeout(function(){

        $('Player.prototype').css({'top':"200px"});
    },350);

    });

/** DEFINING CHARACTER **/

    function Player(x, y) {
        this.dy        = 0;
        this.gravity   = 1;
        this.speed     = 6;
        this.jumpDy    = -10;
        this.isJumping = false;
        this.width     = 60;
        this.height    = 96;
        this.sheet     = new SpriteSheet('imgs/normal_walk.png', this.width, this.height);
        this.walkAnim  = new Animation(this.sheet, 4, 0, 11);
        this.jumpAnim  = new Animation(this.sheet, 4, 3, 3);
        this.fallAnim  = new Animation(this.sheet, 4, 3, 3);
        this.anim      = this.walkAnim;
        Vector.call(this, x, y, 0, this.dy);

        var jumpCounter = 0;  // Maximalna dlzka drzania tlacidla skakania
      }
      Player.prototype = Object.create(Vector.prototype);
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: There..a  lot of code to analyse, that why your jumping not works.. 

but i made a small fiddle,may helps you > http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/VTgvN/

Comment: Thank you Ashish, I have tried your simple script, but tha character is still not moving. I am thinking if I am using the right definition of the player in the brackets - I have tried "Player" and "player.prototype". I have edited the first post with the current code, I would be happy if you could have a look at it. (See EDIT2) Thank you.

Comment: In jquery: $('Player.prototype') means that you have a tag <Player class="prototype">.   I would do: player.anim = player.jumpAnim;  then after a timeout, player.anim = player.walkAnim

Comment: Which plugin you use in your Game..to provide gravity or other ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in http://jsfiddle.net/Ykge9/1/

and you have an infinite loop in animate, the requestAnimFrame should be at the end of the function:

```
 /**
  * Loop cykly hry
  */
  function animate() {

    background.draw();

    for (i = 0; i < ground.length; i++) {
      ground[i].x -= player.speed;
      ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.grass, ground[i].x, ground[i].y+250);
    }

    if (ground[0].x <= -platformWidth) {
      ground.shift();
      ground.push({'x': ground[ground.length-1].x + platformWidth, 'y': platformHeight});
    }

    player.anim.update();
    player.anim.draw(64, 260);
    requestAnimFrame( animate );
  }
```

Comment: Maybe not an infinite loop.. but it slow down the browser enough to not handle key events